# Can we place <select> tag in window.prompt(" "), It is not showing any error, Instead it is showing that [object object]

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to place   tag in the window.prompt();

Is it possible or not?

```
window.prompt(" <input> </input>");
```

This is suggested by some person. But i need to select an option.

Please let me know if it is possible or not.

```
window.prompt(<select> <option> 1</option> <option>2</option> </select>);
```

It is not showing any error. It is showing that [object object].

Is this right way to declare like that or not?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. **Do some research, search for related topics on SO**; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is impossible. The window that comes up is controlled by browser internals and browser internals only, and is not changeable in any way by Javascript (or HTML).